# Edit of headline caused URL to break?

Tags: support, editing, titles, hyperlinks

After posting [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225642/g-is-an-abelian-group-and-a-permutation-t-suppose-that-x-tx-neq-y-ty) I sent the corresponding URL via email to somebody. 
In the meantime a user has edited the headline of my question which rendered my old link invalid. I used the URL in my webbrowser which was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225a642/g-is-an-abelian-group-and-a-permutation-t-suppose-that-x-tx-neq-y-ty/3225753

As a result the person I sent it to had no chance to read the post.

A solution would be to still accept the old url after the edit.

Comment: The link which you have in the post (in [the first revision](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/30275/1)) is invalid probably because you edited it by mistake. To be more specific, you are linking to question [3225a642](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225a642) which does not work (there is no such question), but the link to question [3225642](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225642) does work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have put `a` in the middle of the question identifier (that number after `/questions/` in the URL), which is why the link didn't work.

The link itself only depends on that number, so you can even use `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225642/this-can-be-anything-really-it-doesnt-matter`, and it would work [just fine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225642/this-can-be-anything-really-it-doesnt-matter).